# For documents that get generated with a new version id, how should I handle the old URLs? Robots.txt, 301 redirect, or create permanent URLs?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, 301-redirect, robots.txt

The site I am working on has around 800 products, some of these can have up to 2000 PDF and CAD drawings each.

The links to these PDF and CAD files are combined into a single object and then linked of a product page with the url structure of:

```
$domain/downloads/download/product/$combination_id
```

As there are so many drawings we have created a system that will completely delete the combinations and re-generate them (making new combination_id's in the process)

I have asked Google to not index these URLs and they don't appear in organic search results.

However Google Webmaster Tools has recently indexed the site and has thrown up a huge number of 404s for the old combination ids that have been deleted.

My question is, should I:

1. Block these urls with a /downloads/download/product robots.txt rule?
2. Create 301 redirects for each old combination that would then have to be updated whenever a new version of a drawing is added?
3. "Slugify" the combination_id's so they don't change when the drawings are updated and create 301 redirects for all the existing combinations.

Comment: A URL slug is the portion of the URL that contains words describing the document.   It is usually in *addition to* a numeric ID.   In `/9393.pdf` vs `/9393-widget-guide.pdf` the URL slug would be "widget-guide", but the URL would still have an ID in it.   I think it would be clearer if you said "remove the ID from the URL" rather than "slugify".

Answer (score 1):

By the sounds of it, this is really just one (of many) page that is being *updated* (with PDFs and CAD files), rather than an entirely new page - although that would seem to be how you have currently implemented this.

Consequently I think the URL should remain consistent and not change. So, this relates to your option #3: "*Slugify* the combination_id's so they don't change". You will need to implement 301 redirects for all "old" URLs (combination IDs).

If you blocked the old URLs with `robots.txt` then the URLs themselves could still remained indexed for an extended period of time, as the *redirect* will not be seen. Unless of course your intention is to block *all* product URLs (but I don't think you are really suggesting that)?